# How to reuse footer with only HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is there some solution that will allowing reusing a footer on multiple pages if all you have is HTML/CSS and perhaps javascript?

Comment: apache virtual include

Comment: There are solutions that are fairly easy if you can work with server-side code, such as "includes", but if not, then you will most likely want either an iframe with its src property set to the footer document or you can do an AJAX call for the footer document.

Comment: Do the pages need to reside is HTML files or can it be a single HTML file app ?

Comment: I think that you could use react.js

Comment: You need server-side code, or a static site generator.

Comment: `$('#myDiv').load('path_to_your_html/name_of_your_html.html')`

Comment: React.js was mentioned.  There are also many other javascript frameworks and templating engines like AngularJS etc.  Some of the jQuery solutions mentioned here would work too if you want something quick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could place your footer HTML in a separate file, and then use javascript to load the HTML content of that file, and append it to a div in your page.

```
$("#footer").load("footer.html");
```

Like so: https://plnkr.co/edit/J8qc8221kal11BcPbALj?p=options

Answer (score 5):

Place your code in some html file and then use jquery to include in the file you want. jquery .load() loads data from your server.

```
$('#targetContainerID').load('path/to/html/reuse.html');
```

Have a look at [HTML Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element) as well.

Comment: This is the best solution.

Comment: jQuery seems kind of an overkill to me, just for that... Especially since the OP wrote "and perhaps javascript"...

Answer (score 1):

Save the markup for the footer in the JS or make the JS load it from a file via Ajax, make it append the footer to the page and include the JS in every HTML file.

Answer (score -1):

You could use React.js.
you could use server side templating.
You could use Javascript and Jquery `.appendChild` or javascipt native `element.innerHtml` eg:

`document.getElementById("footer").innerHtml = ....`

Answer (score -1):

there is a way, with HTML import, but this is not supported by all browsers.

[HTML imports](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/)

[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=import)

Comment: This method is now (unfortunately?) deprecated and it's not supported by any browser.